# Ruturn string from multiprocessed imported function real time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function imported from a script that sucessfully runs with multiprocessing(starmap).
My function takes to run a variant time depending on the variable passed.
Is it possible to somehow monitor the process and return a string from the function real time , as this function can take from 1 to 3 mins depending on the arguments passed.I have managed to take the results but when all functions(processes ends).No luck with async too.

sample code:
Main script

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from script import Update_db


list_data = [[data1,data2],[data3, data4]] #the arguments passed in function
pool = Pool()
result = pool.starmap(Update_db, list_data)
#here do something imediendtly when result ends
print(result)
pool.close()
```

The imported function:

```py
def Update_db(data1,data2):

    #do long staff and return a string

    return 'my string'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways.

The easiest is to use `imap_unordered` instead of `starmap`.
This will yield results in the order they *finish*, not in the order they start. In this case, you should either modify `Update_db` to take a single argument, or create a wrapper function that takes a single argument, splits it and calls `Update_db`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from script import Update_db

def wrapper(args):
  first, second = args
  return Update_db(first, second)

list_data = [[data1,data2],[data3, data4]] 
with Pool() as pool:
   for res in pool.imap_unordered(wrapper, list_data):
      print(res)
```

If that is not enough feedback, you would probably need to use a `Pipe` or `Queue`. You would have to modify `Update_db` to regularly put status reports on the queue. In the parent process, you would use `starmap_async`, and create a loop that would print messages from the `Queue` and then sleep for a little bit as long as `AsyncResult.ready()` returns `False`.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) would be better for your problem. I'm not sure if you could achieve it with `starmap` or `starmap_async`.

```py
import concurrent.futures

list_data = [[data1,data2],[data3, data4]] #the arguments passed in function

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = [executor.submit(Update_db, *data) for data in list_data]
    for result in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        print(result.result())
        # do somthing with your result here

results = [result.result() for result in results]
print(results)
```

Comment: `Pool.imap_unordered` does practically the same as `as_completed`; it yields results in the order they *finish* not the order they *start*.

Comment: Hmm that's true but in this case the function `Update_db` would need to be rewritten to take one parameter that is list, and then unpack elements in list. Or to create function that will unpack list and then call `Update_db`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i got it worked like this but i dont know witch is the best way anyway ronald way works too , here is what i got:

```
list_data = [[data1,data2],[data3, data4]]
pool = Pool()
results = []
for i in list_data:
    result = pool.apply_async(self.Update_db, (i[0],i[1]),callback = self.callback_function)
results.append(result)
for r in results:
    result.wait()
pool.close()
```

and then calling the function to do what i want:

```
def callback_function(self,x):
    ###whatever with x returned from imported function
```